# Djangobb in Django app

Tags: django

can we integrate djangobb in django app. means djangobb should use our django application systems auth system instead of its own ??

Comment: i am using this one now.
http://code.google.com/p/django-forum/

Answer (score 1):

DjangoBB uses django Auth System as you can see from its code:

views.py

```
def reply(request, thread):
    """
    If a thread isn't closed, and the user is logged in, post a reply
    to a thread. Note we don't have "nested" replies at this stage.
    """
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?next=%s' % (LOGIN_URL, request.path))
```